# How do I close an open file inside a MS Office application via Java?

Tags: java, ms-office

For example, I've `test.pptx` open in Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 on Windows 10. I want to close it without closing Microsoft PowerPoint itself. How can I do that using Java 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's external program, you need to `kill` your **PC** running **power point** `task`.  
You can achieve it by using below `Java` code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ClosePowerPoint {

    private static final String TASKLIST = "tasklist";
    private static final String KILL = "taskkill /IM ";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {    
        System.out.print(isProcessRunging("POWERPNT.EXE"));

        if (isProcessRunging(processName)) {

            killProcess(processName);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isProcessRunging(String serviceName) throws Exception {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TASKLIST);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line);
            if (line.contains(serviceName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void killProcess(String serviceName) throws Exception {

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + serviceName);

    }   
}
```

Comment: But `taskkill /im powerpnt.exe` will close the PowerPoint application. I don't want to do that. I just want to close the currently opened PowerPoint document but keep the application opened

Comment: so you need extra java library like Apache POI, it can achieve what you want if you willing to use this.

Comment: Yes, so how? Can you provide sample code on how to do it? I already have Apache POI but what is said online is that it can't do what I want.